# How to substitute array value in React.js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

This is my sample code in React.js. I want to use an array `distances` from `Constants.js` in `Main.js`. In particular, the column `APT` in `sampleData` should be substituted by an appropriate `value` from an array `distances` taken from `Constants.js`.

Thus, after clicking on the button `Load data`, the object `csvData` should finally look as follows:

```
NUM,APT,COST
1,483,20
2,5777,25
3,5777,15
```

**Constants.js**

```
export const distances = [
  {label:"KJFK",value:5777},
  {label:"ERTE",value:483}
]
```

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CsvToHtmlTable } from 'react-csv-to-table';
import ReactFileReader from 'react-file-reader';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import {distances} from './Constants';

const sampleData = `
NUM,APT,COST
1,ERTE,20
2,KJFK,25
3,KJFK,15
`;

class CSVDataTable extends Component {

    state={
      csvData: sampleData
    };

    handleFiles = files => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload =  (e) => {
          // Use reader.result
          this.setState({
            csvData: reader.result
          })
          this.props.setCsvData(reader.result)
        }
        reader.readAsText(files[0]);
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
          <ReactFileReader
            multipleFiles={false}
            fileTypes={[".csv"]}
            handleFiles={this.handleFiles}>
            <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
            >
                Load data
            </Button>

          </ReactFileReader>
          <CsvToHtmlTable
            data={this.state.csvData || sampleData}
            csvDelimiter=","
            tableClassName="table table-striped table-hover"
          />
    </div>
    }
}

export default CSVDataTable;
```

I tried the following:

```
function myFunc(item, index) {
  if (item["APT"]=="ERTE") {
    return 483
  }
  else {
    return 5777
  }
}

this.setState({
   csvData: reader.result.forEach(myFunc)
})
```

But the code does not compile after this update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can use something in the lines of

```js
const replacedValues = distances.reduce((acc, d) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`${d.label}`, 'g')
    return acc.replace(regex, d.value)
}, sampleData)
```

This will iterate over all the possible "distances", replace any value equal to `distance.label` with `distance.value` and return the final string with all the changes applied.

In your case you could then do

```js
this.setState({
   csvData: replacedValues
})
```

---

Adding to this answer, you could create a function that dynamically replaces all values that match in a given string with the values from your distances constants.

```js
const replaceDistances = data =>
  distances.reduce(
    (acc, d) => acc.replace(new RegExp(`,${d.label},`, "g"), `,${d.value},`),
    data
  );

// And whenever you load values

this.setState({
   csvData: replaceDistances(reader.result) // or sampleData
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but this works only partly. When I click on "Load data", `csvData` is updated from `reader.result`. How should I change: `this.setState({
            csvData: reader.result
          })`?

Comment: I added a way to make it dynamic so you can use the function whenever you load data. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks. It seems to go through all columns of `data`, right? How can I specify that only column `APT` should be checked? (the second columns). Otherwise, this function seems to change the format of a data column in my real data.

Comment: It depends on your full data and would probably require a slightly more complex RegExp I believe. A simpler way would be using some sort of [csvtojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson) parser. Then map through the resulting array and replace only the "column" you need to replace

Comment: Could you please show this solution? My full data includes an additional column `DATETIME`, e.g. 2016-01-01 04:05:00. Unfortunately, I cannot use the proposed solution with RegEx, because, as I said, it either introduces some symbols in the array or changes a format of `DATETIME`.

Comment: I changed `replaceDistances` slightly to replace only values surrounded by commas. Maybe it helps.