# How to pass arguments to const function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The object `csvData` has 2 ways to get populated:

1. using `sampleData` array
2. by clicking the button "Load data" and getting values from `reader.result`.

In both cases, the values of the column `APT` in `csvData` should be substituted by an appropriate `value` from an array `distances` taken from `Constants.js`. This logic is implemented in `Main.js`.

sampleData:

```
NUM,APT,COST
1,ERTE,20
2,KJFK,25
3,KJFK,15
```

After executing the substitution logic, `csvData` should look as follows:

```
NUM,APT,COST
1,483,20
2,5777,25
3,5777,15
```

The substitution logic is implemented as follows:

```
const replacedSampleValues = distances.reduce(
  (acc, d) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`${d.label}`, 'g')
    return acc.replace(regex, d.value)
  }, sampleData
);
```

Then the option #1 (see above) is implemented as follows:

```
state={
    csvData: replacedSampleValues
};
```

But I don't know how to implement option #2.
How can I apply `replacedSampleValues` to a loaded data (`reader.result`)?

```
this.setState({
   csvData: reader.result   // ???
})
```

Is there any way to update `replacedSampleValues` in such a way that I can pass an array `reader.result` or `sampleData` as an argument?

**Constants.js**

```
export const distances = [
  {label:"KJFK",value:5777},
  {label:"ERTE",value:483}
]
```

**Main.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CsvToHtmlTable } from 'react-csv-to-table';
import ReactFileReader from 'react-file-reader';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import {distances} from './Constants';

const sampleData = `
NUM,APT,COST
1,ERTE,20
2,KJFK,25
3,KJFK,15
`;

const replacedSampleValues = distances.reduce(
  (acc, d) => {
    const regex = new RegExp(`${d.label}`, 'g')
    return acc.replace(regex, d.value)
  }, sampleData
);

class CSVDataTable extends Component {

    state={
      csvData: replacedSampleValues
    };

    handleFiles = files => {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload =  (e) => {
          // Use reader.result
          this.setState({
            csvData: reader.result   // ???
          })
          this.props.setCsvData(reader.result)
        }
        reader.readAsText(files[0]);
    }

    render() {
        return <div>
          <ReactFileReader
            multipleFiles={false}
            fileTypes={[".csv"]}
            handleFiles={this.handleFiles}>
            <Button
                variant="contained"
                color="primary"
            >
                Load data
            </Button>

          </ReactFileReader>
          <CsvToHtmlTable
            data={this.state.csvData || sampleData}
            csvDelimiter=","
            tableClassName="table table-striped table-hover"
          />
    </div>
    }
}

export default CSVDataTable;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to substitute array value in React.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748318/how-to-substitute-array-value-in-react-js)

Comment: I just answered your question on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57748318/how-to-substitute-array-value-in-react-js
I added an example on how you can accomplish just this.